# PDF appearing over the text in latex

Tags: pdfpages

I have the following code in my Latex.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, titlepage]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./Figures/}}

\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
%\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
\usepackage{dirtree}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

%to get clickable links from table of contents
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\newcommand\tab[1][1cm]{\hspace*{#1}}
\setkomafont{sectioning}{\normalcolor\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\caption{SDE set-up for Central Software Development}
\label{fig:sde-chart}
\includepdf[pages=-,width=\textwidth]{SDE-Chart.pdf}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The pdf content is included in my Latex document but it appears over the text which I have written in my report instead of below it separately. What is wrong with my code? The pdf contains only 1 page with a diagram in it.

Comment: `\includepdf` includes full pages and thus cannot be used inside floats like `figure` that only lives in the text area. Use `\inclidegraphics`. Also it is probably more traditional to place the fig caption un der the figure instead of over.

Comment: It works. Thanks. I have by default added the captions above the figure for many of my figures in my report. Is there a shortcut command to shift it to the bottom in one go for all captions? Irrespective of location of the caption command

Comment: There might be a package for that, but I've never used one. I use a powerful editor so finding them by hand is quite easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\includepdf` include entire pages, but floats (like `figure`) live in the text area. Use `\includegraphics` instead.